# Image crop and combine with watermark on website

Tags: javascript, image-processing

I need to develop a website that handles images.
The process will be like this.

1. The user takes a picture of an item.
2. The user uploads the picture to the website and set the area that will be cropped and submit.
3. The website crops the image and combines it with watermark and save it.(Preview function will be a plus)

Is the process doable and practical? Advise me, please.

Thanks.

Sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A website is hosted on a web server - a full blown operating system.  You can use any combination of technologies in the web server.  Your backend code can call literally anything, so there are a million ways to achieve this based on the technologies that you're looking to use.

You should read up a little and decide what language you want to use for your image processing, what libraries in that language, and how you're going to access that language (for example, are you going to use CGI, external calls from .NET/Java servlets, or what?

Until you decide the technologies and libraries you're interested in using you can't get much help here.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you mentioned is doable and reasonably practical.